# How to view all users and change the password

Tags: password, virtual-machine, kali-linux

What I have done is set up a virtual machine using AQEMU/KVM of Kali Linux, the problem is that I don't remember either of my log in details user name / password. So, is there a way to view those details through recovery mode, or with an option with AQEMU? If there is multiple ways to do this, please list all of them since I tend to always run into problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can login as root, or otherwise get a root shell (e.g. with `init=/bin/bash` on the kernel command line when you boot - you do this from grub), you should be able to view `/etc/passwd` to see the list of users (most likely your user will be the one with UID=1000) and use `passwd username` to change the password.

if you use the `init=/bin/bash` method or similar, you will have to remount the root fs as read-write before changing the password.

```
mount -n -o remount,rw /
```

and remount it as read-only again before rebooting

```
mount -n -o remount,ro /
```

If you had to use this method, you will probably need to change root's password too.  just run `passwd` without a username to change the password of the current user (root)

Comment: Oh, cheers, I'll try that in a bit, when I can.